# Entity declaration inside EAR

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, ear, java-ee-7

This is the structure of my projects:

```
AppEjb -> DAO, Remote Beans
AppEjbClient -> DTO, Interfaces
AppEjbEAR -> The EAR with additional libs
AppWS -> The Web Service, using AppEjb with @Inject and @EJB
```

Right now, my entities are all inside `AppEjb` and I use the `DTO` to transfer one entity to the `WebService` call.

I would like to declare my entities inside my `AppEjbClient`. But when I do this, all my queries stop working with the following error message:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM User]. 
The abstract schema type 'User' is unknown.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Where's the right place for persistence.xml?
If possible, I wouldn't like to have to type every entity in my persistence.xml.

Comment: You know, that in ejb-3.1 you do not need to deploy that as EAR anymore. You can put everything in one WAR-module.

Comment: Thank you @aschoerk! I don't know that. Do you have anything you recommend me to read about? Are you suggesting that I should put *all* my source inside a single project and deploy it as a WAR? What's the point in having the EAR option, then?

Comment: some think it positive to have separate classloaders for some classes. Kind of extra modularization. But if the separate classloaders are not important, yes, you can put everything in one module. Some use anyway separate jar-files, if the entities are in their own jar, you might have to maintain the classes in persistence.xml. You must decide about a good structure. You even do not need any web-module in your war-file, in spite of that your ejbs can be used even remote via JNDI. We work in my team this way any time using JBoss7.